# XML OleObject GetChildNodes

Tags: ole

So I have the following xml:

```
<ElementList>
    <Element>   
        <Row1>row1text</Row1>
        <Row2>row2text</Row2>
    </Element>
</ElementList>
```

I use the following code to get info out of it:

```
OleObject loo_element

loo_element = xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//ElementList/Element[1]')
print(loo_element.item[0].text)
```

This gives me the akward output:

```
row1textrow2text
```

I would like to have the object initialized like this:

```
loo_element.item[0].text = row1text
loo_element.item[1].text = row2text
```

How can I achieve this? Guessing I need to alter my XPath somehow in SelectNodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as this:

```
loo_element = xmlDoc.SelectNodes('//ElementList/Element[1]/*')
```